# Test result output duplicated

Tags: playframework-2.0, scalatest

I'm using play framework 2.2.1 and would like to use scalatest instead of specs2. So i added scalatest dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"
```

I also rewrote the tests using `FunSuite`:

```
class AppTest extends FunSuite {

    test("Application sends 404") {
        new WithApplication {
            assert(route(FakeRequest(GET, "/asdf")).isEmpty)
        }
    }

    test("Application renders index") {
        new WithApplication {
            val home = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/")).get
            assert(status(home) == OK)
            assert(contentType(home) == Some("text/html"))
            assert(contentAsString(home).contains("Hello world"))
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run `test` from the play console (or sbt) I get the test results twice:

```
[info] AppTest:
[info] - Application sends 404
[info] - Application renders index
[info] AppTest
[info] + Application sends 404
[info] + Application renders index
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for test AppTest
[info] Finished in 0.021 seconds
[info] 2 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

It is not a big problem, because I don't think the tests are actually executed twice, but it is a little confusing, especially when there are more tests.

Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plus signs and lack of a colon indicate that the second one is from a specs2 test class. I think you must have left it lying around, so sbt runs both of the ScalaTest one and the specs2 one.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I couldn't find any reference to it. I think the play sbt plugin adds it as a dependency and I don't know how to remove it.